# Create Dynamic Table using Response data in reactJS

Tags: django, reactjs, axios, react-bootstrap

My question is, I want to print table in reactJS. I have already use axios to get data from django views and I got a response. But, I don't know who to set this data in table format. I have used Table of react-bootstrap. And I am very new in ReactJS.
My Code Snippet is:

```
change(){
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/')
.then(function (response) {
  console.log("in user",response.data[0].id);
  this.setState({
    id: response.data[0].id,
    username: response.data[0].username,
    email: response.data[0].email,
});
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

}

But Now how to use this id, username, and email in "tbody" tag? Please Guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your render function where you used react-bootstrap  Component. Just use

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>{this.state.id}</td>
    <td>{this.state.username}</td>
    <td>{this.state.email}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I have tried but, i got an error.. But I found the solution. Thank You Sir.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually only saving to state one element, you should save to state the resulting array of data.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

export default class example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            users: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/')
            .then(function (response) {
                this.setState({
                    users: response.data,
                });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        const { users } = this.state;
        return users.lenght > 0 ? (
            <table striped>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td>Username</td>
                        <td>Email</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {users.map((user) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={user.id}>
                                <td>{user.id}</td>
                                <td>{user.username}</td>
                                <td>{user.email}</td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        ) : (
            <h1>No data available!</h1>
        );
    }
}
```